# Accessing multiple arrays of data with different numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am having difficulty accessing data inside of an array. Each array has its own number. Then there's an array inside of that. I want to display the `name` from the array.

I want to access the data like this:

```
source.tag.#ANY NUMBER#.name
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
Foo, Bar, Baz
```

**Attempt 1**

```
InnerHTML={{__html:source.tag}}
```

Result:

```
[object Object]
```

**Attempt 2**

```
InnerHTML={{__html:JSON.stringify(source.tag)}}
```

Result:

```
{"1":[{"name":"Foo"}],"2":[{"name":"Bar"}]}
```

**Attempt 3**

```
InnerHTML={{__html:source.tag ? source.tag.map(item => item.name).join(', ') : ''}}
```

Result: Nothing

My data looks like this:

```
"title" : "Test item"",
"tag" : {
  "1" : [ {
    "name" : "Foo"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Bar"
  } ],
  "2" : [ {
    "name" : "Baz"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the data, you need the bracket notation as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for access of keys as number and indices, like

```
source.tag[1][1].name // Bar
          ^^^         // key of tag
             ^^^      // index
```

```js
var source = { title: "Test item", tag: { 1: [{ name: "Foo" }, { name: "Bar" }], 2: [{ name: "Baz" }] } };

// single access
console.log(source.tag[1][1].name);

// get all names
Object.keys(source.tag).forEach(function (key) {
    source.tag[key].forEach(function (element) {
        console.log(element.name);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If we take your example:

`myObj = {"1":[{"name":"Foo"}],"2":[{"name":"Bar"}]};`

then to access e.g. the "Foo", you need to do this way:

`console.log(myObj["1"][0].name);`

The script will print **Foo** as a result.

If you want to iterate over the whole object, then do the following:

`for (var key in myObj) console.log(myObj[key][0].name);`

Comment: I don't want ONE result, I want all the results

Answer (score 1):

The object you have mentioned contains extra (") character. At first omit this extra (") character. Then you will be able to console the names as mentioned bellow:

```
class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: 'Tests item',
      "tags" : {
        "1":[{
              "name" : "Foo"
            },
            {
              "name" : "Bar"
            }],
         "2" : [ {
                "name" : "Baz"
              } ]
      }
    };
  }
```

As you can see I have used your data in local state. So now it's to possible to access name of each tag as mentioned bellow:

```
 console.log(this.state.tags["1"][0].name)
```

For real example please Run it.

```js
class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: 'Tests item',
      "tags" : {
        "1":[{
              "name" : "Foo"
            },
            {
              "name" : "Bar"
            }],
         "2" : [ {
                "name" : "Baz"
              } ]
      }
    };
  }
 transformTags() {
    const newTagItems = [];
    Object.keys(this.state.tags).forEach((key) => {
        this.state.tags[key].forEach((item) => {
            newTagItems.push(item.name);
        })
    });
  return newTagItems.join(',');  
}
  render(){
   // console.log(this.state.tags["1"][0].name)
  return (
    <div>
    <h4>{this.state.title} </h4>
    <p>{this.transformTags()}</p>
         </div>
  );
}

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <User/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="ReactJS tags">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each property of data.tag which will yield an array, and for each of those properties/arrays, loop through each array element, adding the name property of that element to the growing string, plus a comma. At the end, remove the last comma. The code shows two different ways of accomplishing this.

```js
const source = {
  title: "Test item",
  tag: {
    "1": [{
      "name": "Foo"
    }, {
      "name": "Bar"
    }],
    "2": [{
      "name": "Baz"
    }]
  }
};

let str1 = '';
for (let prop in source.tag) {
  for (let elmt of source.tag[prop]) {
    str1 += elmt.name + ',';
  }
}
str1 = str1.slice(0, -1);
console.log(str1);

let str2 = '';
Object.keys(source.tag).map(num => {
  str2 = source.tag[num].reduce((s, e) => s + e.name + ',', str2);
});
str2 = str2.slice(0, -1);
console.log(str2);
```